# Using refresh token in ajax post request

Tags: javascript, ajax, oauth-2.0

I currently only have access to a section of a website (a form) and I'm supposed to use OAuth 2. I was able to get the access token and I'm able to post data to the client's api however, they want me to use a refresh token since the access token expires. Since I only have access to the client side, where do I add the refresh token in the ajax call? I can't seem to find anything other than it's dangerous to do so.

```
"headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer RANDOMSTRING"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First yes it's not a good practice to storage the Refresh token on the client, because usually the expiration time it's very long. If you have to storage this token on the client you have to take precautions.

The API shouldn't permit to make request of resources with a refresh token, this token must be only use to get a new access token.

There are a couple of methods to pass the refresh token depending on the API but the most common is to put the grant_type to refresh_token.

In OAuth the basic flow is the following:

1. You send the request with your access token
2. If the response indicates that the token is no longer valid you have to send the refresh token to obtain a new access token
3. You resend the request with the new access token

Hope this helps

More information about refresh token: https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/